# JScripts funcionam em uma view mas em outras não!

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Em meu projeto tenho uma `view` "Index" onde eu uso o seguinte script:
        `<script>$('#search').focus();</script>`

Funciona normalmente nessa `view` "Index", porém se dentro dessa view eu ter uma tabela com alguns dados onde eu tenho um botão para editar e eu clico nesse botão eu serei redirecionado para uma `view` "Edit". E se eu por esse script dentro desse "Edit" ele não irá funcionar.

Obs: O mesmo acontece se eu tentar usar um script no _Layout e dentro desse layout ter um RenderBody.

**Edit1:**

Código resumido da View que funciona:

```
  @model IEnumerable<RamalAguia.Models.Usuario>
  <head>
     <title>Awsd</title>      
  </head>
  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

  //Tabela

  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var $rows = $('#ramaltable   tr');
     $('#search').keyup(function () {
        var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

        $rows.show().filter(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).hide();
  });
  </script>
  <script>
       $('#search').focus();
  </script>
```

E esse o da view que não funciona:

```
  @model RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel
 <head>
    <title>asd</title>
 </head>
 <body>

     //Edit

     <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

 </body>
```

**Resolvido:**

Na minha view `_Layout` eu estava referenciando o jquery dessa maneira:

```
 <script src="Content/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Mas quando troquei essa linha para:

```
<script src="~/Content/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Os scripts funcionaram normalmente.

Comment: Da algum erro de Javascript? Nas views que não funcionam, elas possuem JQUERY? tem como postar o código?

Comment: Não da erro algum, e possuem JQuery.